Дефис как исключение: юго-запад. Почему дефис и соединительная гласная одновременно?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ
— Это философский вопрос, и решение должно быть соответствующее. Если соединительная гласная только соединяет, то дефис может соединять или разделять. Соединять второй раз не имеет смысла, поэтому дефис, вероятно, разделительный, то есть он отменяет соединение.
— Зачем же нам сначала соединять с помощью гласной, а затем разъединять с помощью дефиса?
— Вот это самый интересный момент. Мы хотим, чтобы выбранная форма письма выражала не соединение или разделение, а нечто среднее. Мне эта тема и раньше была интересна. А теперь после разговоров о дефисе добавилось новое понимание знака.
О соединительной и разделительной функции дефиса и тире

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ

Соединительная гласная в сложных существительных

Юго-восток, направление меду югом и востоком.
(1) Связь сочинительная, но с оттенком подчинения. Поэтому мы не можем написать юг-восток по аналогии с только сочинительной связью: хлеб-соль, вопросы-ответы. Соответственно, приходится использовать  соединительную гласную, как при подчинительных отношениях (между югом и востоком).
(2) Но в большинстве случаев при наличии соединительной гласной существительные пишутся слитно (это норма), отражая только  подчинительную связь между основами.
(3) Тогда предлагается ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ: дефис с разделительным значением используется вместе с соединительной гласной. Тогда не будет  полного слияния (юговосток), но не будет и полного разделения (юг-восток).
Так будут обозначены как сочинительные, так и подчинительные отношения.

Соединительная гласная в сложных прилагательных (для сравнения)

Обозначение сочинительной (дефис) или подчинительной (слитно) связи исходных основ.
Финско-русский.
Соединительная гласная при наличии дефиса здесь норма (нельзя написать финский-русский), но слитные написания в этой теме тоже встречаются.
И тогда возникают возникают ПРОБЛЕМЫ — что взять за исходное сочетание.  Выбор слитной или раздельной формы написания сложных прилагательных — один из самых сложных вопросов в орфографии:
(1) Нужно различать белоснежный (белый снег, подчинение) от снежно-белый (снежный и белый, сочинение).
(2) Иногда первая основа является основой существительного/усеченной основой прилагательного, и тогда появляются парные словарные решения: англо-русский словарь, отражена сочинительная связь, английский и русский), хлебобулочные изделия (новое слово, хлеб + булка + суффикс Н).

Путается ли словарь?

Путается обычно Викисловарь: краснобурый — некорректное написание по словарю РАН, его нет и в Карте слов.
Предложения со словом КРАСНО-БУРЫЙ Исходное сочетание: красный и бурый.
Но проблемы у пользователей все же бывают. № 250787
В рекламе нашего КСК клуба "конноспортивный" написано по- 
разному. В одних буклетах "конно-спортивный клуб", в других 
"конноспортивный клуб".Как правильно (а или б)?
а) предпочтительно: "конноспортивный", допустимо: "конно- 
спортивный" б) правильно: "конноспортивный", некорректно: 
"конно-спортивный"

 ОТВЕТ. Правильно слитное написание: конноспортивный. 
 Некорректно: конно-спортивный.

Исходное сочетание: конный спорт, а не конный и спортивный.
ПРАВИЛО. ПАС, § 119, 120
§ 119. Следующие разряды существительных пишутся слитно:
3. Сложные существительные с соединительными гласными о и е, 
напр.: водопровод, земледелец, лесостепь, птицеферма, 
овощехранилище, новостройка, южноамериканцы, звукообраз, 
силлаботоника; с двумя и более начальными компонентами: 
лесоторфоразработки, пароводоснабжение, стекложелезобетон, 
газоводонефтенасыщение.

§ 120.  Следующие группы существительных, образуемых с соединительными гласными пишутся через дефис (как отступление от правила § 119, п. 3):
а) названия сложных единиц измерения, напр.: койко-место, 
машино-место, пассажиро-километр, тонно-километр, самолёто- 
вылет, станко-час, человеко-день;

б) русские названия промежуточных стран света: северо-восток,
северо-запад, юго-восток, юго-запад, а также северо-северо-
восток, северо-северо-запад, юго-юго-восток, юго-юго-запад;

Краснобурый и подобные словосочетания употреблялись в некоторых географических журналах, вроде "Вокруг света". Вероятно речь шла об оттенке - краснобурые листья(не то красные, не то бурые). А если речь шла о палитре или листьях разного рода, то писали красно-бурые листья.

Сочинение бывает однородным или неоднородным, но в обоих случаях пишется дефис. Слитное написание обозначает подчинительную связь. Разве здесь есть такая связь? Норма http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49 пункт 11. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов:
бледно-голубой,
блёкло-розовый,
бутылочно-зелёный.

"Чернобурая лисица, или серебристо-чёрная лисица" объясните. И еще разбор по составу сделайте у "серебристо-черный". "Нордост" - без соединительной гласной слитные слова возможны в РЯ?

Чернобурая лисица/чернобурка - это видовое название животного, дефис нежелателен, а серебристо-черная - это скорее цвет.  Норд-ост заимствованное слово, дефисное написание взято по образцу англ. и нем. письма.  Сейчас в ПАС разрешены подобные формы: § 121, пункт 3 http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66
